# Swiftui - problem with nested navigation link

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a view with a list of items exposed with LazyGrid. When one of these elements is clicked, I should move to the edit page, but for this seemingly simple thing I'm having several problems.

Initially I inserted the navigation link including graphics and destination in the foreach. But the target view is invoked for each element before perform a click on the object. Following the click, however, it enters an infinite loop. Even stranger, trying toby removing the viewmodel of the target view, the initialization is repeated only for "2*cList.count" times.

To overcome this, I've taken the navigationDestination out.
Now when on click the target view is initialized "cList.count" times and almost immediately the target view is backed up, not having time to see it. Also in the console I get this error: "A navigationDestination for “PEM.Category” was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used."

What I wrong?

My Code now

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var etvm: EditTransactionViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack{
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Main").font(.subheadline)){
                        NavigationLink() {
                            InnerListView2(selectedCategory: .constant(nil))
                        } label: {
                            Text("Row")
                        }
                        .isDetailLink(false)
                        .navigationTitle("Outer List")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct InnerListView2: View {
    @FetchRequest (
        entity: Category.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Category.name, ascending: true)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "rootCategory == nil")
        
    ) private var cList: FetchedResults<Category>
    
    @Binding var selectedCategory: Category?
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Root Categories").font(.subheadline)) {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible())], spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(cList, id: \.self) { c in
//     OPTION 2                               NavigationLink(value: c) {
//                                        SelectableCategoryView(category: c, showEdit: true)
//                                    }
                                NavigationLink(destination: InnerInnerListView2(ecvm: .init(category: c))) {
                                    SelectableCategoryView(category: c, showEdit: true)
                                }
                                .isDetailLink(false)
                                .navigationTitle("Inner List")
                               
                            }
                        }
//   OPTION 2                 .navigationDestination(for: Category.self) { c in
//                            InnerInnerListView2(ecvm: .init(category: c)
//                        }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct InnerInnerListView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var ecvm: EditCategoryViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Row \(ecvm.wrappedCat.iconName) " )
    }
}


struct ContentView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView2(etvm: .init())
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
@MainActor class EditCategoryViewModel: ObservableObject {
        var storedCat: Category?
        @Published var wrappedCat: InputCatModel
        
        @Published var hasError = false
        
        let isNew: Bool
        private let provider = PersistenceController.shared
        
        init(category: Category? = nil, in context: NSManagedObjectContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext) {
            
            print("Eccomi")
            
            self.storedCat = category
            
            if let category, let existingObj = provider.exisits(category, in: context) as? Category {
                self.wrappedCat = .init(category: existingObj)
                self.isNew = false
            } else {
                self.wrappedCat = .init()
                self.isNew = true
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

For Test:

```
@main
struct testApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView2(etvm: .init())
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
                .onAppear(perform: { setDefCategories(persistenceController.container.viewContext) })
            
    }
    
    func setDefCategories(_ viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        
        // MARK: Root Category
        
        let e1 = Category(context: viewContext)
        e1.name = "Generico"
        e1.icon = "cart"
        e1.isIncome = false
        e1.rootCategory = nil
        e1.colorId = "IconColor1"
        
        let e2 = Category(context: viewContext)
        e2.name = "Spesa ed Alimenti"
        e2.icon = "cart"
        e2.isIncome = false
        e2.rootCategory = nil
        e2.colorId = "IconColor2"
    }
}
```

Comment: This really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't run this code as you are supplying data with a `@FetchRequest` and there is a lot of extra code that is not necessary to show the problem. Reduce this to the minimal amount of code that runs, and shows your issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm happy that the error I made is not trivial enough to be detected by a simple static check of the code. I tried cleaning from useless code. But I have added some code used in the test project to insert elements for the fetch and also the calling view as I noticed that if I just call EditCategoryView, the error doesn't show up, so I guess there is something wrong with the navigationlink nesting .

PS. I left the ViewModels, because, as written in the question, I still have a different behavior, when they are there, than when I try to remove them.